# How to make brighter the connection used in Network Notification

Tags: 11.04, network-manager, notification

In Ubuntu 11.04 using Unity or Gnome Classic the same visual bug is there. The option selected for a network connection is not highlighted enough so it is very hard to know which one is selected. In the following picture you can see the example where no option appears brighter than the others so i do not know which one is the one selected in case where i want to share a connection or have several connection options available.

[image]

UPDATE - Just in case nobody noticed. The **Intel* and **Auto Ethernet** options can both be selected using the first card there (The Wired Intel 8255DC-2). The problem is that the **Auto Ethernet** does not appear highlighted or brighter than the **Intel** option which can also be selected with the same NIC. Do not confuse the picture with the gray options. You can even notice that the Disconnect option is the same bright white than the "Selected" option.

UPDATE2 - In the following image from Ubuntu 10.10 you can see that the highlighted connection is more BLACK than the rest. In my case, in the original theme, the option should be more WHITE than the rest.

[image]

Ubuntu 11.04 with more options to show what i mean.

[image]

As you can see in the image, the Intel connection has the same color than the Shared and Realtek ones. If i had more it would confuse more the problem since with a quick glance i would not be able to find the one used at the moment.

**So what option do i need to edit to change the selected connection to a brighter color?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem in your picture, the greyed out menu items are the ones that are not selected. The Auto Eth0 is the one you are connected to.

Comment: The Auto Ethernet and the Intel can both be selected with my Wired Network (Intel) card. There SHOULD be a brighter or something that makes the Auto Ehternet in that picture brighter than the Intel option. The picture was to show that part. It is ibvious that the gray part is other things not selected.

Comment: @CYREX: Why should they highlight one over the other when you are connected to both???

Comment: To know which one you are using. In my case to know which connection option was selected in case am sharing my connection via wire. In ubuntu 10.10 the highlighted one was the one used by the device and i always could see which one was the one used by this. Now am suppose to guess which one

Comment: I have uploaded an image from Ubuntu 10.10 showing what am asking. In this image the option is more BLACK since the theme is white. In the default theme from Ubuntu 11.04 the option should be more WHITE since the theme is black.

Comment: @CYREX: then why don't you just change your theme....

Comment: Yes but that would be like finding a problem in linux and someone saying to move to Windows ;). I REALLY like the default theme from Ubuntu. When i say really i mean that i have search for many themes that i felt were better and never did i find a more better one than this. It is good for the eyes (The color black soothes your eyes and makes monitors last more than the white color for example) and i find it more "Eye-Candy" like-able than the white theme. Do not know if you feel the same one. The white theme mention above is from my girlfriends laptop dv6000

Answer (score 0):

Change the theme by right clicking the desktop and clicking Change Desktop Backgroud, click the theme tab and select one you like -- I would suggest Radiance.

Comment: I do not want to change the theme. The default one is the one i like and enjoyed in Ubuntu 10.10 with no problem related to this.